# Как сделать асинхронную операцию в PHP?

Tags: php

**Задача:**

Сделать интерфейс в котором, есть кнопка и по её нажатию улетает команда на выполнение очень объёмной выборки, данные которой надо записать в большое кол-во файлов с сложной иерархией директорий.

**Комментарий:**

Это будет тяжелая выборка с которой сервер справится не менее 30 секунд. Создание файлов и директорий  чуть меньше по времени. И понятное дело, что всё это может выполняться ещё дольше. Пользователь ждёт.... И это печально.

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать так, чтобы запрос к БД выполнялся фоном (и работа с файлами), т.е. на фронт скрип дал ответ(например о том, что задача выполняется) не дожидаясь выполнения работы с БД и записью файлов, и по завершению работы скрипта (или процесса) записать лог? Реализуемое такое на PHP?

Comment: дак вы и выполняйте аякс запрос, можете там же и через какой-нить SSE ему присылать уведомления о прогрессе загрузки.

Comment: @teran 1. Что такое `SSE`? 2. Так отправился запрос, как сделать так как я описал выше? Я просто узнал об существовании асинхронного `php` и стало интересно.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events? с аяксом то вы знакомы?

Comment: хотя с учетом того, что в ИЕ SSE походу до сих пор не поддерживаются, то применение ограничено.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял. На стороне сервера должен быть бесконечный цикл (`EventLoop`). Собственно в процессах висит скрипт, в котором описана логика работы с БД и файлами?

Comment: нет, вместо бесконечного цикла вы выполняете свою работу по которую описали в вопросе, и иногда отправляете клиенту сведения о том, что уже сделали. Но тут будет проблема с возможным разрывом соединения. Можно сделать скрипт который будет делать работу, и кидать лог куда нить в таблицу БД, а второй запрос с sse будет в бесконечном цикле брать из бд и отдавать клиенту.

Comment: @teran Т. е. так как нативный `php` пока синхронный, он закончит свою работу только после того, как выполнятся все команды и блокирующие операции. Тогда зачем нужны либы типа `ReactPhp`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100857/discussion-between-doox911-and-teran).